# Possibility of a number line that has variable density.

Tags: real-analysis

In my real analysis class, I have been informed that if you have a continuous line say $[0,1]$, and you do a mapping say $A\to B$ such that any element in $A$ is equal to $B^2$, where $A$ is every element in $[0,1]$  you would ultimately get a line that is denser toward the $0$ and less dense toward the $1$.

I have two question regarding this result,

1. Can we note that every element in $A$, say variable $a$  has both its square and square root already existing in the line $[0, 1]$, therefore the mapping is only an exchange of the position of points,

for example we know that if we have point $0.5$

both $0.5^2$ and $\sqrt{0.5}$ exist in $[0,1]$  therefore if we do the mapping, $0.5 \mapsto 0.25$ doesn't the other point $\sqrt{0.5}$ replaces $0.5$'s original position ?

1. How is it possible that you can have a denser part in a continuous line, does this not ultimately suggest that there will be a gap around the $1$'s side?

Any comment would be much appreciated

Comment: How would you define density in this context? It is possible to define a *measure* of $\mathbb R$ (or a bounded sunbinterval) that fails to be translation invariant, though.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but from what my instructor described, there will be more element from the result of the mapping toward the zero side. But I feel like maybe my understanding of his word is fundamentally erroneous.

Comment: Your argument could be viewed as the observation that the function is one-to-one onto, so it maps any set into a set of the same cardinality. Perfectly true. But from another point of view, there is a squeezing towards $0$. That point of view is very useful in probability theory, for example.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Here $A$ and $B$ are the same set. Even if we take $A=[0,2]$ so that $B=[0,4]$ then sets have the same cardinality. What exactly does density mean?

Comment: @AndréNicolas  what point of view would you be looking at?

Comment: Depends which hat I am wearing, the set theory hat or the proability hat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is meant by the statement that the line is "more dense" towards 0 is this: say that you pick some small number $\epsilon>0$. Then the interval $[0,\sqrt{\epsilon}]$ all gets mapped (by $x\mapsto x^2$) in to the interval $[0,\epsilon]$; so, the preimage of $[0,\epsilon]$ under this map has total length $\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

On the other side, the numbers $[\sqrt{1-\epsilon},1]$ are mapped by $x\mapsto x^2$ to the interval $[1-\epsilon,1]$; so, in this case, the preimage of $[1-\epsilon,1]$ has length $1-\sqrt{1-\epsilon}$.

The interesting thing here: even though the intervals $[0,\epsilon]$ and $[1-\epsilon,1]$ have the same length... their preimages do not.  In fact, for every $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, it turns out that $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ (the "size" of the preimage of $[0,\epsilon]$) is larger than $1-\sqrt{1-\epsilon}$ (the "size" of the preimage of $[1-\epsilon,1]$).

So, all that they really meant was that different intervals of $[0,1]$ get more or less "spread out" by the mapping $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am still a little confused, as shouldn't the cardinality be the same before and after mapping for the case of [0,1]? And how would you have a denser line, if the set of real is already dense(no gap)?

Comment: The cardinality is the same, yes. What we are talking about is a different way of assigning sizes to sets - called _measure_.  You'll learn the gory details eventually; for now, just think about the fact that if we restrict our attention to intervals $[a,b]$, there is a very natural notion of size: namely the _length_ $b-a$. And the mapping $x\mapsto x^2$ is interesting because it maps some intervals to bigger intervals, and other intervals to smaller ones.

Comment: For instance: the first half of the interval (that is, $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ gets entirely mapped in to $[0,\frac{1}{4}]$, while the last half $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ gets mapped in to $[\frac{1}{4},1]$. So even though we start off with two equal pieces, their images under the maps have (quite) different length.

Comment: So from the example you gave, I keep thinking that $[1/2,1]$ to $[1/4,1]$ will not be dense anymore, so the resulting number line would not be continuous, am I getting something wrong?

Comment: No, they will still be dense.  Remember, $f(x)=x^2$ is a continuous function - so, there are no "gaps".  I think you are trying to associate this new idea of the measure of a set with the number of elements in the set... and in this context, that won't work!  Clearly, any interval has the same cardinality; I'm just saying that if you draw them, they take up different amounts of space.

Comment: I think I kind of see how is it less dense now here is what I got so far: the resulting number line from the mapping $A$ $->$ $B$ is the result from forcing the curve of $f(x)=x^2$ to the y axis, and we know the derivative of $x^2=2x$ therefore it make sense the point's toward the $1$ is less dense, however I still don't see how is it possible for you to compress a set of point to another set that is already dense, this is like saying I would like to insert some random element $z$ into the set of real, which is not logical, I must be missing something here

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly: this is just one of those things about infinite sets that takes some getting used to.  You're still thinking that somehow the interval $[0,1]$ has placeholders in it for each of its elements... that somehow the number of elements has to correlate to the size.  But it just plain doesn't.  Think about the fact that $x\mapsto 2x$ is a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$, for instance.

Comment: It make total sense now, thank you so much